# Enable IO accounting inheritance in the Linux kernel only for specific applications

Tags: linux-kernel, io

The Linux kernel does IO accounting, it calculates how many pages of data the process has read and written (`IO_READ/IO_WRITE`).

Here's the issue: when an application launches another application which does IO and the latter application exits, the former application inherits (adds) the exited application IO read/write stats.

This could make sense for multiprocess applications like e.g. Chrome or Firefox.

However it doesn't make any sense for e.g. your desktop environment.

Here's an example: I'm under XFCE. I launch an application from my desktop. It exits. Now the xfce-session process has added all the IO stats of the exited application. I do not want that or I want to have an option of enabling this behavior only for certain applications.